# Can I reverse an iron redox reaction with potassium hydroxide and electricity?

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry, redox, home-experiment

For a school project, about clean energy, me and my team are trying to build an iron battery. We are using a piece of iron (anode), potassium hydroxide (electrolyte), carbon electrode (cathode) arranged as shown below:

[image: Iron Battery Diagram]

As to generate electricity from the following chemical reactions:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Fe + 2 OH- &-> Fe(OH)2 + 2 e-}\tag{1}\\
\ce{3 Fe(OH)2 + 2 OH- &-> Fe3O4 + 4 H2O + 2 e-}\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

Then:

\begin{align}
\ce{O2 + 2 H2O + 4 e- &-> 4 OH-}\tag{3}\\
\end{align}

And the overall reaction is:

\begin{align}
\ce{3 Fe + 2 O2 &-> Fe3O4}\tag{4}\\
\end{align}

Will this succeed in producing some electricity? And, can the redox reaction be reversed by having an external power source with sufficient voltage like a car battery, then hooking the negative terminal to the iron and the positive terminal to the carbon electrode?

Comment: A redox reaction in a battery can often be reversed by plugging an external power source; this is known as electrolysis. Now what is your reaction? I see two half-reactions, and both are on the same side. What is on the other side? Where do these electrons go?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Will the carbon electrode not take in the electrons given off by the iron redox reaction?

Comment: Two oxidation half-reactions are shown, but what is the reduction half-reaction? What is the overall redox equation? Where does the iron oxide enter in? This needs some re-working.

Comment: @user10560552 **No.**

Comment: @IvanNeretin Is this better?

Comment: @EdV Is this more in the right direction?

Comment: Replacement for previous comment. Looking at the standard reduction potentials in wikipedia, I think the proposed cell will work as a galvanic cell, but the iron oxide is ferric oxide, not magnetite. I doubt it can be recharged, but you can always try! Anyway, have a look at the standard potentials and good luck!

Comment: @EdV Thanks for the helpful information

Comment: Yes, this will do. I don't believe the product will be Fe3O4, but that's an unimportant detail. Also, there is not much O2 in water, so the current will be rather low.

Comment: One last comment. As per @IvanNeretin oxygen content will be low, so maybe *gently* sparge in some air near the carbon electrode. A simple glass frit aquarium bubbler will do. **But wear eye protection, respect KOH, and do not splash KOH solution on yourself or anything else. If you do any sparging, use water as a test case first, to get a safe *gentle* flow rate.**